# How do I suppress all error messages in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, warnings

I have included a static library subproject that has over 1000 warning messages that, after testing, appear to be inconsequential to the overall project.  How can I suppress these messages for this subproject that I don't intend to touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add -w (lowercase) to your warning flags.

Here is a link:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html